# Can you move characters/worlds from mobile to pc in terraria

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

This is probably a dumb question, but I'd really like to know. My mother is giving me her laptop, and I really don't think I can go through The Twins or getting the materials for the Ankh Charm again. If you know of a way, please tell me. I'd be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

My intuition is that this is not currently possible. The mobile version is on a different content patch, but there are also quite a number of things that are mobile only. Moreover, the mobile version is made by a different developer group than the PC version.

I suppose the real question here is, can you transfer the player and world files from iOS/Android to PC? I have not tried the process myself, but looking at files, they are different extensions, which *might* imply that they are different formats.

A [user over at the TouchArcarde forums seems to have tried the process](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?p=2958336#post2958336), though:

> I tried many ways and you can't transfer characters from ios to PC or vice versa, you can transfer worlds and characters from ios to ios though. Will see what else I can come up with later this week. The ios uses .player and .world where as PC uses .wrd and .plr
>
> If you rename the PC world to .world and transfer it into the documents of terraria mobile it does read it and load it but it gets stuck in a boot loop, constantly at the loading stage. This is on an iPhone 5 and I only waited 5 minutes, I'm confident there is a way to get this data to work as with a hex editor the world file is very very similar, just the extension they have changed.

It might be possible to actually edit the world and player files such that they work on a different platform, but I think that would require a decent amount of knowledge of how data is stored in the files and how the games loads that data.

Answer (score 2):

I've attempted this before (Android to PC) and it does not seem to be possible. The file structures are very different and I would also like to point out that the mobile world size is smaller than the PC small.

Since your concern is that you don't want to have redo the fights or farm for the materials I would suggest that you create a new world and use a 3rd Party software, such as TEdit, to modify your world.  From there you can just add an Ankh Charm to a chest, life hearts, life fruit, and your current armor and weapons.  You can also use TEdit to change the world properties, such as which bosses have been defeated and if hardmode has started.

One warning though.  This can be a very tempting way to cheat and just give yourself the best armor/weapons and all the money you would like.  You may want to delete the 3rd party software after you bring your new world up to speed.

(Personally I use TEdit to save myself time, it's great for skipping material collecting so I don't waste 8 hours collecting materials or spawning new worlds just to strip all their floating islands and take all the ocean sand.)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how to help about the world but I do know the way for the item/character:

1. Download terraria inv editor.
2. Turn on your terraria on android/ios.
3. Turn on PC terraria.
4. Create a character, and name it after your character on android.
5. Save.
6. Go to terraria inv editor.
7. Just put all things you have on the android save with the name of your character on pc via inv editor.

Comment: what is "terraria inv editor"? i found TEdit but it doesn't support mobile

Answer (score -2):

This is now possible if you have are looking to transfer to an iOS device. Connect the device to itunes, open the files named apps, and drop your PC files into it :)